# Changing the variable you omit due to the dummy variable trap

Tags: self-study, categorical-data, econometrics, standard-error, regression-coefficients

I've got a quick question. The practice exam on which I have the question is **linked below** and its the **first question**

As you can see, **column (3) and (4)** on the table are both the same except the dummy variable they omit is different.

We've been asked to work out the coefficients and standard errors for the new regression which changes the omitted variable and I've worked out all the new coefficients but I don't know how to work out the **new standard errors** of the 4 location dummy variables.

[Practice Exam - The relevant q is Question 1](http://www.scribd.com/doc/226030716/Practice-Questions)